# How to pass ScatterData from service to activity in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Experts,

Below flow is what I learned to get a chart on Android.

The requirement is refresh the chart(data keep updating) every a few seconds and immediately show.
And somehow the data is big, it caused 1~2 seconds the activity no response.

My question is: how to prepare the data and the chart in a SERVICE, then just save the chart as a picture(.png for example) to a path. And the ACTIVITY fetch and show the picture from that path.

Since the SERVICE keep running in background, when I click a button on the ACTIVITY, it would immediately show the picture, no need to wait for the data preparing(already done in the SERVICE)

Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ScatterChart sDtdChart; // 1. define a chart called sDtdChart

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ScatterData data = getData();
    sDtdChart.setData(data); //3. attach data to the chart

    //4. chart's other setting
    //XXXXXX

    sDtdChart.invalidate(); //5. refresh the chart
}

// 2. prepare data for the chart
private ScatterData getData(){
    //XXXXXX
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you please show a [mcve] instead of a snippet?

Comment: let me explain: the //prepare data portion is prepare data for mChart to use, it takes time. the //render chart portioin render the chart used the data prepared.  I would like to do the //prepare data portion in a service since it takes time.  (mChart is a ScatterChart type defined in MPAndroidChart)

Comment: A Service or an AsyncTask? Either way, please [edit] to include additional information